# Use DB::select + binding too select a row

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I'm trying to get a row from the database but when using binding. I know that this doesn't work because the query automatically puts single quotes so it will be like this: `select model, magazine, round('name', 2) etc.` This doesn't work of course but how do I get rid of the single quotes?

`$merkinformation = DB::select('select Model, Magazine, round(?, 2) as Rondetijd from rondetijden where Merk = ? order by ? limit 3;', [$track, $merk, $track]);`

Comment: $track seems to be a columnname that is not possible with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use column nmaes like this. 
You must concatinate the name of the column. But this is **vulnerable** to **sql injection**.  So you must check if $track has a valid content

```
$merkinformation = DB::select('select Model, Magazine, round(`' . $track . '` , 2) as Rondetijd from rondetijden where Merk = ? order by ? limit 3;', [$merk, $track]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this

Answer (score 0):

there is ['] single quote and [`] punctuation mark. If start with single quote or double quote mysql will translate that as string where punctuation mark will be recognize as field name.

Are you sure that is a single quote ?

Comment: I'm not 100 per cent sure that is a single quote but when I try to do the same SQL statement (with a single or double quote) in my workbench it will give the exact same result as I get now so with all the information except for the round() it will give 0 because he can't find that column because it is in quotes...